# retrieve username for two different ID's in same view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I am trying to get a list of linked users in to a MVC view & I am struggling!!!

**Users table** has an int ID and a varchar name

**User Roles Table** has int holderid, int officerid & int role id

**Roles table** has int id and varchar description

ID in users table is linked to both holder id & officer ID in user roles.

Role id is linked to id in roles

From my controller I am passing in one user ID to a strongly typed user role view. That view displays the name for the user id fine. Each user id will have multiple rows in user roles table, each with a different officer id.

**My Issue**

My issue lies in the fact that I cannot display the name from the users table that relates to an officer (or at least I can’t work out how to perform this in the view!! Or whether it should be done elsewhere in fact.)

Really what I want to do is say:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.users.name.where(item.userid == item.officerid)
```

But this doesn’t seem to be working. I get this error: 'string' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and the best extension method overload
Can anyone offer any advice??

Comment: it would be better if you could post a screenshot of your db

Comment: What does `modelItem` look like? (Which type, properties)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`item.users.name` is a string. And you cannot use `where` on it. Instead try something like this

```
item.users.Where(item.userid == item.officerid).FirstOrDefault().Name
```

Now here `users` is a table, hence a collection.

And are you working without `Intellisense` ?